# Adding a button in dynamic TableViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a label of dynamic size in a TableViewCell. I have pinned it to up,down,left and right and set Lines to 0 and it is working fine. Next, I add a button below the label and and pin it to top and left. and fix the width and height. But I am getting an error at runtime

```
 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you   don't want.
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you    
don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or   
constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing  
 NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the 
 documentation for the UIView property  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
 (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc302f600 UILabel:0x7fcbc3034010'Digestion of food  in the...'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc30334a0.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc3037e30 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc30334a0.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7fcbc3034010'Digestion of food  in the...'.bottom + 38>",
   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc303a920 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V: [UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc30334a0(43.5)]>"
 )

 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
 <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcbc3037e30 
 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcbc30334a0.bottomMargin ==
 UILabel:0x7fcbc3034010'Digestion of food  in the...'.bottom + 38>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful. Here is the screenshot of my layout
```

[image: Screenshot]

Which constraint should I remove? I don't think I have added extra constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these constraint for as per your requirements:
[image: img1]

[image: img2]
OR
Follow these links [Autolayout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) or [Autolayout programatically](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder check that there are no warnings (the yellow arrow on the side of the vc inspector) and check that the height of the label +the button and the margins don't exceed the cell height.

Also you said you pinned to the top, of what? The container or the label?

Comment: The cell height is dynamic with the size of the label. I just want the button to appear below the label text. Pinned to the top of label

Comment: Then the top of the button should be pinned to the bottom of the label. It is a custom cell i suppose right? Can you show a screen of your layout? Be sure the label height does not exceed the height of the cell.

Comment: Can you please check the layout once?

Comment: Try to set the label lines to 1. It wont probably have any issue. Then if you need to show more lines you may need to further adjust something ( decrese text size or increase cell height or decrease margins)

Comment: Not working. Only the buttons get displayed in the first row, not the text.

Comment: Set a height for the label too as constraint

Answer (score 0):

```
                           (OR)
```

For some reason, Xcode generates own default set of auto layout constraints on a NIB at build time. This is why I couldn't add any more manual constraints, because they were conflicting with the automatically added ones.

I resolved this the following way:

Open up the Storyboard view controller you're handling.

Select the view controller and select Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > All Views in [ ] View Controller > Add Missing Constraints from the menu:
[image]

This will ensure that no additional build time constraints are created and all the constraints are now visible.-->Select all the constraints from your view controller:
[image]

This will ensure that no additional build time constraints are created and all the constraints are now visible.-->Check from the right pane the following check box: Placeholder - Remove at build time:

[image]

(This will ensure that no additional build time constraints are created and all the constraints are now visible.)

Now you can add all the auto layout constraints manually in the code.

Comment: Yes but this often mean a bad usage of autolayot, even more since it is explixitely telling you there are layout issues (the res mark)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to provide some more info than that regarding the values you set in auto layout like the distance of the UILabel from top margin,down,left etc.

The problem might be that you specified the UIButton to be from top margin , it should be with respect to your UILabel as its below it so set the UIButton's **vertical spacing** property to the UILabel this makes sure the UIButton is placed below it.